# How to add a search filter (facet) option for a custom field in CKAN

Tags: python, python-2.7, ckan

How can i add a search filter option (facet) for my custom field in my CKAN instance?
[image: search page] i.e. I want to add an option to the left side-bar in this image.

I've used CKAN Theme integration in my extension to replace CUSTOM search filter instead of Groups and organization. But I want to add custom serach filter for a custom field I have created while adding dataset.

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IFacets

Is this possible to add a custom search filter? Please help me if anyone can know about that.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, your datasets have an additional (custom) field and you want to add a **facet** to the search, to enable users to search (filter) by that field.

The docs you quote show an example of how to change an existing facet 'groups':

```
facets_dict['groups'] = p.toolkit._('Publisher')
```

(because 'groups' already exists in the `facets_dict`) and also to add a new one:

```
facets_dict['secondary_publisher'] = p.toolkit._('Secondary Publisher')
```

So you simply need to add your custom field as a new key in the `facets_dict` like this latter example.

Comment: this problem has been solved i have created plugin with custom facets

Comment: Please will you either mark this answer as the correct one, or create a new answer with the actual solution. That will help others in the same position as you who come looking here, and is how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Just for those stumbling across this, I'm including a bit more detail **but the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32590952/3366016) is correct**.

To implement, you can update your `plugin.py`, implement IFacets for your plugin and then use the `dataset_facets()` function (or the proper `*_facets()` function) to add your new facet.

```
# plugin.py
# encoding: utf-8

import ckan.plugins as plugins


class ExampleIFacetsFunctionsPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IFacets)

    def dataset_facets(self, facets_dict, package_type):
        '''Add new search facet (filter) for datasets.
        This must be a field in the dataset (or organization or
        group if you're modifying those search facets, just change the function).
        '''
        # This keeps the existing facet order.
        facets_dict['secondary_publisher'] = plugins.toolkit._('Secondary Publisher') 

        # Return the updated facet dict.
        return facets_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3366016's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53381687/11329034) was very helpful but I wasn't completely correct. ckan.plugins.toolkit needs to be imported.

This way the code works:

```
# plugin.py
# encoding: utf-8

import ckan.plugins as plugins
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as toolkit


class ExampleIFacetsFunctionsPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IFacets)

    def dataset_facets(self, facets_dict, package_type):

        facets_dict['secondary_publisher'] = toolkit._('Secondary Publisher') 

        # Return the updated facet dict.
        return facets_dict
```

Comment: thanks for flagging my typo.  I import plugins, then use plugins to get the toolkit `p.toolkit`. But as you helped point out, `p.toolkit` doesn't work in this case. It should be `plugins.toolkit` or i should change my import to `as p` and all subsequent references to `plugins`.  I have now updated.